# Merging Multiple XLSX sheets in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this working but not how I want. I have multiple Excel sheets I am trying to merge into one. What I am running into now is it just putting the data from the other sheets side by side instead of merging the data that has the same header value in the individual sheets.

So I need the final output to merge the data, but if the header value is the same in the file to merge it under one and not duplicate.

here is my code:

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/Desktop/' + folder + '/Import Files')

frames = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in glob.glob('*.xlsx')]
all_data = pd.concat(frames)


all_data.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I have been torturing my brain to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I've tried that and it still just put the data side by side

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
folder = r'\\Filepath'
cwd = os.getcwd()

os.chdir(folder)

files = os.listdir()
dfs = []
for i in files:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(i))
Raw = pd.concat(dfs,sort=False,axis=0) 
os.chdir(cwd)
```

heres some example code of me doing the same thing, go to folder, open a bunch of csvs and append them into one file. Raw is the final result

edit, key thing your missing is axis, it need to be 0